# Parsing cURL command from Java code causing an error

Tags: java, curl

i'm trying to parse some cURL command:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Token token_key" \
-d '{ "query": "query" }' \
https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/findById/fias
```

but my version:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "curl",
                "-X", "\"POST\"",
                "-H", "\"Content-Type: application/json\"",
                "-H", "\"Accept: application/json\"",
                "-H", "\"Authorization: Token token\"",
                "-d", "\"{ \"query\": \"query\" }\"",
                "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/findById/fias");
```

throwing an error:

```
{"family":"CLIENT_ERROR","reason":"Bad Request","message":"Unexpected character ('q' (code 113)):
was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1); 
line: 1, column: 4]"}2020-08-28 19:37:03.961 ERROR 3692 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : 
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] 
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to decode [/dadata/  % Total    % Received % Xferd  
Average   Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

Could someone help plz? Thanks for any help

Comment: Don't quote the arguments, `ProcessBuilder` will do that as needed. E.g. use `"-X", "POST",` without any `\"`. You still have to quote the JSON name and string value, of course.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, but that did not help. Im now connecting through HttpURLConnection and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will be helpfull for someone

```
String request = "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/findById/fias"

URL url = new URL(request);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token token");
JSONObject query = new JSONObject();
query.put("query", "query");

OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(query.toString());
wr.flush();

InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
```

Found the solution here https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/java/post-solicitud-enviar-datos-json-java-httpurlconnection/1043548240/